# Should "What is your favorite book on the topic of INVESTING?" be reopened?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Question: [What is your favorite book on the topic of INVESTING?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/12/6564)

Should the question be re-opened? Discuss.

I feel, both the question and its answers contribute great content to this SE, its members, and the internet. I believe it should be re-opened. Possibly protected or edited if the community feels so.

Answer (score 6):

When this was closed, I commented

> ... matches the FAQ "What kind of questions should I NOT ask here?"
>   question: every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite
>   **__**?”

I still feel that this poll question where every answer is valid doesn't fit well in the stack exchange model.

Comment: Agreed. This is too subjective and can't be answered definitively. However, it is possible that this could be re-phrased in such a way that it could be answered definitively.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question for which the current moderators have a difference of opinion.  :-)

I personally think that some list of books questions can be of value.

Note that we have been discussing the issue (more generally) here:   [Do "list of books" questions have value?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/436/do-list-of-books-questions-have-value) ...  The answers there could use some more community votes and discussion .. there is not yet a clear enough consensus.

Comment: :)  I think the questions need to be phrased so that every answer is *not* equally valid.   Best book for a narrow subject (for example).  I just don't think "Investing" is a narrow category.  Maybe blue chip stocks, REITs, etc.

Comment: Interesting.  This question has my answer as highest voted.  The list of books question has my answer as lowest voted.   In both answers I say very similar things. :)

Answer (score 1):

On my own blog I share my [Book List](http://www.joetaxpayer.com/joes-book-list/), and I think such lists are of value. 
I do think that with some dialog here, it's possible to categorize by topic, for example, there are a genre of books that deal with "the crash" which used to mean 1929, but now include the more recent crashes. Such books are not "how to invest" books, but books that serve a great historical purpose.

There are books like Millionaire Next Door, again with a lesson to teach, but not a book on investing, per se.

Then you get into the books for actual investing, stock picking, asset allocation, etc.

My person feeling is a list, by genre, and a 1-3 sentence summary, would be valuable. The same way we debate whether questions here are on topic or in some other class, the books will spark the same issue.